# How to make a copy of an existing config file using nant

Tags: security, configuration, nant

I was wondering if there is any way to make a copy of an existing web.config file(rename the newly created file) with the nant build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nant Task Reference](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is a copy, then the [`copy` task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/copy.html) is your friend.